# servertool in Windows

Tags: java, corba

I started one cmd and orbd there.

```
C:\A2Server>orbd
```

Then I started another cmd and typed the following:

```
C:\A2Server>java com.sun.corba.se.impl.activation.ServerTool -cmd register -server a2server.A2Server -applicationName A2Server -classpath ./dist/A2Server.jar
```

But I got the error "Bad server definition: main class not found".

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium x64, and jdk1.7.0_17. A2Server is the main class of the project and the server. It's in the a2server package. And the .jar file is in the dist directory under A2Server.

Anyone could tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What's right? Where did you get that command from? Who said it would work?

Comment: There must be something wrong with it but I couldn't tell it.

Comment: You haven't answered either of my questions.